# Escribir de manera dinámica el estado de un atributo del objeto en un archivo csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

Con el siguiente código genero un archivo csv en el que escribo en columnas una serie de objetos que he ido generando en la simulación (ejemplo mínimo reproducible y completo abajo):

```
writer.writerow(
                            [
                                sim + 1,
                                mu + 1,
                                jugador,
                                ronda,
                                patron,
                                muestras[mu]["b"],
                                muestras[mu]["x"],
                                muestras[mu]["m"],
                            ]
                            + aux
                            + [summation_pop]
                            + [shannon(summation_pop)]
                        )
```

**Objetivo**

Ahora estoy intentando escribir de manera dinámica en una nueva columna del archivo csv el atributo del objeto denominado `self.nueva_i` (el cual genero dentro del método `def jugar`), para cada simulación, muestra, ronda y jugador. Este atributo, `self.nueva_i` es una lista que contiene 4 valores (en el ejemplo debería ser `[0.5, 0, 0, 0.5]` y mantenerse constante durante las simulaciones).

**Intentos**

He estado intentando seguir una estrategia similar a la que seguí para escribir la variable `aux` por medio del objeto `estadísticas`.

Es decir, primero, dentro de la clase `Partida` crear un atributo del objeto que adjunte en cada simulación, jugador, muestra y ronda los valores de `self.nueva_i`:

```
self.memoria_nueva_i = list()
```

Y dentro del método `def jugar` añadir una línea de código para ir adjuntando los valores de self.nueva_i:

```
self.memoria_nueva_i.append(self.nueva_i)
```

Aquí es donde viene el problema, pues no consigo acceder a los valores del atributo de manera dinámica desde la función `main()` para escribir la nueva columna correctamente.

Se agradecen comentarios.

```
from __future__ import division
from random import random
from bisect import bisect
from collections import deque, Counter
import numpy as np
from skbio.diversity.alpha import shannon
import csv


def choice(opciones, probs):
    probAcumuladas = list()
    aux = 0
    for p in probs:
        aux += p
        probAcumuladas.append(aux)
    r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
    op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
    return opciones[op]

class Jugador:
    def __init__(self, nombre, senales, sigma, b, x, m, menLen):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.senales = senales
        self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.__mem_mostradas = deque(maxlen=menLen)
        self.__men_observadas = deque(maxlen=menLen)
        self.sigma = sigma[:]
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m

    def memoriza(self, mostrada, observada):
        self.__mem_mostradas.append(mostrada)
        self.__men_observadas.append(observada)
        mostradas = Counter(self.__mem_mostradas)
        observadas = Counter(self.__men_observadas)
        self.mem_mostradas = { signal: mostradas.get(signal, 0) for signal in self.senales }
        self.mem_observadas = { signal: observadas.get(signal, 0) for signal in self.senales }

    def __str__(self):
        return "Jugador_{}".format(self.nombre)

    def with_b(self, muestra, observa, r, idx):
        if not (muestra == observa == 0):
            result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * self.b * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        else:
            result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * 0 * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        return result

    def choose(self, r, nueva_i):
        probs = [
            self.with_b(
                self.mem_mostradas[op], self.men_observadas[op], r, indx
            )
            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)
        ]
        elecc = choice(self.senales, probs)

        #Aquí es donde se necesitará llamar a self.sigma y nueva_i
        print(self.sigma)
        print(nueva_i)

        return elecc

class Partida:
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, sigmas, b, x, m, menLen):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.jugadores = {
            nombre: Jugador(nombre, senales, sigmas[nombre], b, x, m, menLen)
            for nombre in jugadores
        }
        self.memoria = list()
        self.entropy = float()
        self.nueva_i = np.mean(list(sigmas.values()), 0)

    def generar_senales(self):
        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores, self.senales))
        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = {}
            for jugador in self.jugadores.values():
                eleccs[jugador.nombre] = jugador.choose(r, self.nueva_i)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs

    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
        for ronda in self.emparejamientos:
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)
            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].memoriza(observada=senales[jugador2], mostrada=senales[jugador1])
                self.jugadores[jugador2].memoriza(observada=senales[jugador1], mostrada=senales[jugador2])
            # Calcular la media de las sigmas de la ronda anterior
            i = [jugador.sigma for jugador in self.jugadores.values()]
            self.nueva_i = np.mean(i, 0)



def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"]
    emparejamientos = [[(1,2),(3,4)],
                       [(3,2),(1,4)]]

    patron = 1
    menLen=1

    s1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
    s2 = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    sigmas = {1: s1, 2: s1, 3: s2, 4: s2}

    muestras = [{'b': 0.0, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 1.0, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02}]

    muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(1)]

    simulaciones = 1

    estadisticas = {
        sim: {
            jugador: {
                muestra: {
                    senal: [0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1)]
                    for senal in senales
                }
                for muestra in range(len(muestras))
            }
            for jugador in jugadores
        }
        for sim in range(simulaciones)
    }

    for sim in range(simulaciones):
        for mu in range(len(muestras)):
            juego = Partida(
                jugadores,
                emparejamientos,
                senales,
                sigmas,
                muestras[mu]["b"],
                muestras[mu]["x"],
                muestras[mu]["m"],
                menLen
            )
            juego.jugar()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                    estadisticas[sim][jugador][mu][senal][n] += 1

    with open("datos.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(
            csvfile, delimiter=";", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
        )
        writer.writerow(
            ["Sim", "Muestra", "Jugador", "Ronda", "Patron", "b", "x", "m"]
            + senales
            + ["sumpop"]
            + ["shannon"]
        )

        for jugador in jugadores:
            for sim in range(simulaciones):
                for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                    for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1):
                        aux = [
                            estadisticas[sim][jugador][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux1 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][1][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux2 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][2][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux3 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][3][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux4 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][4][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]

                        summation_pop = []
                        for i in range(len(aux1)):
                            summation_pop.append(aux1[i] + aux2[i] + aux3[i] + aux4[i])
                        writer.writerow(
                            [
                                sim + 1,
                                mu + 1,
                                jugador,
                                ronda,
                                patron,
                                muestras[mu]["b"],
                                muestras[mu]["x"],
                                muestras[mu]["m"],
                            ]
                            + aux
                            + [summation_pop]
                            + [shannon(summation_pop)]
                        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

En esta autorespuesta comparto una solución práctica pero seguramente poco elegate y poco "pythonica", como se dice. Poco elegate y recomendada porque utiliza una variable global y porque relee un archivo csv dos veces.

He procedido así:

Creación de una variable global:

```
memoria_nueva_i = []
```

Dentro de `def jugar(self):` utilizar el método append para adjuntar `self.nueva`:

```
memoria_nueva_i.append(self.nueva_i)
```

A continuación, debajo del código, escribir la lista en una nueva columna utilizando `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datos.csv')
df['nueva_i'] = pd.Series(memoria_nueva_i)
df.to_csv('datos.csv')
```

Como digo, no es una solución elegante ni eficiente, pero funciona.